# Android - How to import library from Maven Central?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I want to use zt-zip library in my project. Library page on github says that I should have this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
    <artifactId>zt-zip</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

I used to add dependency in this way for other libraries. For zt-zip I could not find dependency like this:

```
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

So I tried this:

```
compile 'org.zeroturnaround.zt-zip:1.8'
```

Unfortunately getting this error:

> Error:Failed to resolve: org.zeroturnaround.zt-zip:1.8

I have tried to add mavenCentral() and maven() with url:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Still getting this error:

> Error:Failed to resolve: org.zeroturnaround.zt-zip:1.8

Question: how to add dependency from Maven Central?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dot in

```
compile 'org.zeroturnaround.zt-zip:1.8'
```

try with a colon

```
compile 'org.zeroturnaround:zt-zip:1.8'
```

Comment: Yes, I changed dot to colon. Now it is importing - very good. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/) is your friend. Just do a quick search for your desired package and it will return the correct format for Maven, Ivy, Gradle and more.  In this case, you need to write the dependency as:

```
compile 'org.zeroturnaround:zt-zip:1.8'
```